# child action data lost on refresh

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Thanks in advance the help. I'm very new to MVC. Currently I'm working in MVC 4. I have the following layout which is referenced in _viewstart (note this is VB syntax). In it, I'm using a child action to render a menu, based on an xml file. It works fine when I first run the app; however, as soon as I refresh the page or move to different URL in the app, the menu is lost.

```
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("Logo Here", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        @Html.Action("Menu", "_MenuBar")
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Here is the partial view:

```
     @ModelType IEnumerable(Of MenuItem)
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
     @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
     @Code
       For Each item In Model
         @:<li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, item.Action, item.Controller)</li>

       Next
     End Code
```

And here is the child action called in the controller called from _layout:

```
    Public Class _MenuBarController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    <ChildActionOnly>
    Function Menu() As PartialViewResult
        Dim filePath = Server.MapPath("~/bin/Conf/MenuData.xml")
        Dim menuBar As List(Of MenuItem) = MenuResolution.GetStandardMenu(filePath)
        Return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_MenuBar.vbhtml", menuBar)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: are you sure that you what to store the menu items in an xml file? what will be happening if 1000 of users will be working with your site?

Comment: I'm sure I want the menu items there, but it will be cached so that the xml only gets read once.

Comment: I'm not a VB guy but it looks fine, it should be working..